# I am getting the error test_verified_email - TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable.This error happens the 1st time I run the code. Why is this?

Tags: python, flask, pytest, flask-sqlalchemy

I am getting the error test_verified_email - TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable. This error happens the 1st time I run the code. Why is this?

**conftest.py**

```
@pytest.fixture()
def new_user():

    
    # why can't I go plaintext_password() instead of plaintext_password 
    
    plaintext_password = 'pojkp[kjpj[pj'
    hashed_password = bcrypt.hashpw(plaintext_password.encode('utf-8'), bcrypt.gensalt())  
    current_user = User(username='fkpr[kfkuh', hashed_password=hashed_password, email=os.environ['TESTING_EMAIL_USERNAME'],
    confirmation_email=False, reset_email_password=False)
    return current_user
```

1st time running the code, the code works.

**test_routes.py**

```
@pytest.fixture()
def add_and_delete_database_try(new_user):            
    try:
        db.session.add(new_user)
        db.session.commit()      
        db.session.delete(new_user)
        db.session.commit()
    except:
        # what does rollback do vs delete and commit?
        db.session.rollback()



def test_verified_email(token_client, new_user, add_and_delete_database_try):   
    response = token_client.get("/verified_email<token>", follow_redirects=True)
    assert response.status_code == 200
    with token_app.test_request_context():
        add_and_delete_database_try(new_user)
```

2nd time running the code it runs

**test_routes.py**

```
def test_verified_email(token_client, new_user, add_and_delete_database_try):   
    response = token_client.get("/verified_email<token>", follow_redirects=True)
    assert response.status_code == 200
        with token_app.test_request_context():
            try:
                db.session.add(new_user)
                db.session.commit()      
                db.session.delete(new_user)
                db.session.commit()
            except:
                db.session.rollback()
```

Here is the error.
https://pastebin.com/EuFx5aNT

Comment: where/how :  the function  test_verified_email is called?

Comment: I just run python -m pytest and it runs.

Comment: oh i see, you are doing unitTest. actually the eror says you call a variable that the value is NoneType. I am not sure with line is that trigger the error.

Comment: Which line, exactly, gets the error?

Comment: It doesn't say. I added the error to the question, so you can confirm. I may be wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[A `@pytest.fixture()` is not meant to be callable itself](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/fixture.html); it's meant to be used in a test's signature, and to return or yield an object (a fixture) to be used in the test.

Since you don't return anything from that function, it's probably not meant to be a fixture at all:

```
def add_and_delete_database_try(new_user):            
    try:
        db.session.add(new_user)
        db.session.commit()      
        db.session.delete(new_user)
        db.session.commit()
    except:
        # what does rollback do vs delete and commit?
        db.session.rollback()



def test_verified_email(token_client, new_user):   
    response = token_client.get("/verified_email<token>", follow_redirects=True)
    assert response.status_code == 200
    with token_app.test_request_context():
        add_and_delete_database_try(new_user)
```

Comment: If I remove  ```@pytest.fixture()``` I get ERROR at setup of test_verified_email  'add_and_delete_database_try' not found. Any suggestions?

Comment: @kihnihih If you look closely, I removed that from the signature here. You should too.